# Which object should hold the many-to-many relationship in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm just learning Django and have a quick question: I see that when creating a model you can define a many-to-many relationship between two objects. While you assign this relationship to one of the objects, Django actually creates a third table to resolve this M:N relationship. Given this, does it matter which object holds the many-to-many field or can it appear on either of the two, related objects? (coming from a relational DB background, I've got to say that the concept of assigning the M:N to one table feels a bit odd - I'm still not over the idea of not starting with an ER diagram)

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't matter. It can go on either of the two.